# Remove partition from table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, partition

I have created table "example"

```
create table example
(
    id varchar(255) not null,
    name varchar(255) not null
) partition by hash (name);
```

and then 5 partitions

```
create table example_p0 partition of example for values with (modulus 10, remainder 0) partition by range (name);
create table example_p1 partition of example for values with (modulus 10, remainder 1) partition by range (name);
create table example_p3 partition of example for values with (modulus 10, remainder 2) partition by range (name);
create table example_p4 partition of example for values with (modulus 10, remainder 3) partition by range (name);
create table example_p5 partition of example for values with (modulus 10, remainder 4) partition by range (name);
```

I can remove partitions using

```
ALTER TABLE example DETACH PARTITION example_p0
```

But how can I remove partition by hash from the main ("example") table? So that no one will be able to make partitions of this table.

Comment: What do you mean "no one will be able to make partitions"? What is wrong with detaching partitions by name?

Comment: I want to ban the ability to create partitions, so I need to remove partition by hash from existing table "example"

Comment: Why would removing partitions limit the ability to create partitions? Only the owner and superusers can create partitions anyway.